# AngularAMD: the app depends on services but services depend on the app

Tags: angular-amd

I am clearly missing something very basic.

[The instructions](https://github.com/marcoslin/angularAMD) are to create an app, like this:

```
define(['angularAMD'], function (angularAMD) {
    var app = angular.module(app_name, ['webapp']);
    ... // Setup app here. E.g.: run .config with $routeProvider
    return angularAMD.bootstrap(app);
});
```

And then create subsequent items like this:

```
define(['app'], function (app) {
    app.factory('Pictures', function (...) {
        ...
    });
});
```

And there is this helpful line:

> Any subsequent module definitions would simply need to require app to create the desired AngularJS services

Well that's just great for *subsequent* module definitions, but `app.config` and `app.run` need lots of *prerequisite* modules that I am supposed to create -- as would any application beyond the level of a toy.  So there is obviously some simple solution that I am missing.  How do I create services that the app depends on?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use 'angularAMD' injection to create services.
For example,

```
define(['angularAMD'], function (angularAMD) {
  angularAMD.service('LoggerService',['$log',function($log){
     return function(msg){
        $log.log('message:', msg);
     }
  }]);

});
```

The services created using this method are available before the application is bootstrapped. Hence app can depend on these services.

More similar code can be found at [angular-AMD](https://github.com/marcoslin/angularAMD-sample) sample app.